# Deploy on release config results in exception "Failed to find constructor for type MvvmCross.Core.MvxSettings"

Tags: android, xamarin, nullpointerexception, mvvmcross

I used the MvvmCross star wars sample (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/StarWarsSample) as a project to begin with, adjusted it to some of my needs and tried to deploy it on a google pixel 4.

I do only have the core and droid project without iOS.

Starting the app in debug mode works fine.

Starting the deployed app an error occures see:[visual studio exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttUj5.png)

**LogCat Stacktrace:**

> 06-09 21:33:24.491: I/MonoDroid(24322): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   06-09 21:33:24.495: I/MonoDroid(24322): System.ArgumentNullException: missing source event info in MvxWeakEventSubscription
>   06-09 21:33:24.495: I/MonoDroid(24322): Parameter name: sourceEventInfo
>   06-09 21:33:24.495: I/MonoDroid(24322):   at MvvmCross.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`2[TSource,TEventArgs]..ctor (Android.Views.View source, System.Reflection.EventInfo sourceEventInfo, System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] targetEventHandler) [0x0001d] in :0 
>   06-09 21:33:24.495: I/MonoDroid(24322):   at MvvmCross.WeakSubscription.MvxWeakEventSubscription`2[TSource,TEventArgs]..ctor (Android.Views.View source, System.String sourceEventName, System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] targetEventHandler) [0x00012] in :0 
>   06-09 21:33:24.495: I/MonoDroid(24322):   at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.WeakSubscription.MvxAndroidTargetEventSubscription`2[TSource,TEventArgs]..ctor (Android.Views.View source, System.String sourceEventName, System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] targetEventHandler) [0x00000] in :0 
>   06-09 21:33:24.495: I/MonoDroid(24322):   at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.WeakSubscription.MvxAndroidWeakSubscriptionExtensions.WeakSubscribe[TSource,TEventArgs] (TSource source, System.String eventName, System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] eventHandler) [0x00000] in :0 
>   06-09 21:33:24.495: I/MonoDroid(24322):   at MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerViewHolder.OnAttachedToWindow () [0x00074] in <6dcdb499fdcb47abb57d7957137b06a2>:0 
>   06-09 21:33:24.496: I/MonoDroid(24322):   at MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerAdapter.OnViewAttachedToWindow (Java.Lang.Object holder) [0x0000e] in <6dcdb499fdcb47abb57d7957137b06a2>:0 
>   06-09 21:33:24.496: I/MonoDroid(24322):   at AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget.RecyclerView+Adapter.n_OnViewAttachedToWindow_Landroidx_recyclerview_widget_RecyclerView_ViewHolder_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_holder) [0x0000f] in :0 
>   06-09 21:33:24.496: I/MonoDroid(24322):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.55(intptr,intptr,intptr)

**(10.Jun.2020) Edit1:**
Change title from "Failed to find constructor for type MvvmCross.Core.MvxSettings#" to 'Deploy on release config results in exception "Failed to find constructor for type MvvmCross.Core.MvxSettings"'

**(10.Jun.2020) Edit2:**
Inserted the following snippets into LinkerPleaseInclude.cs

```
public void Include(MvxSettings mvxSettings)
{
    mvxSettings = new MvxSettings();
}

public void Include(MvxStringToTypeParser mvxStringToTypeParser)
{
    mvxStringToTypeParser = new MvxStringToTypeParser();
}
```

Now there seems to be an error after MyApp.Droid.Setup.CreateApp() but before or in MyApp.Core.App initialization.

As there are no async methods in there it seems like there has to be another reason for the freeze at that point.

Comment: Found the source of the issue. The Linker removed parts of the framework.

Comment: were you able to fix it?

Comment: Yes. There is a linker that kinda links the libraries and SDKs. Disabling that linker solved it.

Comment: What is the linker you mean?

Comment: This linker is the one i meant.
[link](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-linker/)

Comment: @N.Brühl Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like discussed in the comments it's a trimming issue.
We've upgraded to .NET 8 from .NET 6 and in .NET 7/8 trimmode copyused is removed.

Replacing *copyused* by *partial* in the android.csproj worked for us.

```
    <TrimMode>partial</TrimMode>
```